# NullPointerException during application run

Tags: android

When running my application it is stooped with null pointer exception.

problem occurring in 4th line

```
1. Bundle arguments;

 2.arguments = getArguments();

 3.String viewType=arguments.getString("viewType");

 4.if(viewType.equals("weekly"))
{
......
}
```

Is there any solution? please reply.

> 08-16 11:31:03.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2675): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-16 11:31:03.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2675): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   08-16 11:31:03.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at com.nv.netmdapp1.ScheduleCreateDialog$1.onClick(ScheduleCreateDialog.java:188)
>   08-16 11:31:03.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at com.nv.netmdapp1.customViews.CustomAlertDialog$Builder$1.onClick(CustomAlertDialog.java:110)
>   08-16 11:31:03.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
>   08-16 11:31:03.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14109)
>   08-16 11:31:03.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>   08-16 11:31:03.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   08-16 11:31:03.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   08-16 11:31:03.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>   08-16 11:31:03.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   08-16 11:31:03.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   08-16 11:31:03.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   08-16 11:31:03.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   08-16 11:31:03.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

This is the error log.Any Idea?

Comment: post the stack trace and the relevant code

Comment: check if viewType is null

Comment: It's mean that you arguments bundle doesn't contain string "viewType"

Comment: viewType seems to be null. where u r defining viewType.

Comment: post your full code here..

Comment: This nullPointerException seems to be related to UI elements? Please post more code!

Comment: Please, always post the full method and all variables relevant to the scope!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4.if(viewType.equals("weekly")) ---> 4.if("weekly".equals(viewType))

Comment: viewType == null, you can coding like if(viewType.equals("weekly")), but you need ensure viewType is not null, or you can add a default value such as "".

Comment: My problem was that viewType==null.So that I put a string value into bundle.Then it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are not properly referencing you bundle variable. Please try the below code:

```
Bundle arguments =  this.getIntent().getExtras();
String viewType=arguments.getString("viewType");
```

And the rest shall remain the same.